# How can I play a DVD using an external drive on a Surface RT?

Tags: dvd, microsoft-surface

I have a Surface RT, I have an external DVD drive with a USB plug, and I have a DVD (actually, quite a few) that I want to watch on it.

- I don't want to rip or convert the DVD into some other format that I can access from the Surface with a MicroSD or over the network.
- I don't want to put the DVD in another machine on the network and "play to" the Surface

I don't know if either of those approaches would even work, I just think they are unworkable for being tucked up in bed or on the couch and wanting to watch a movie or part of a TV season by popping a DVD into a player. And I know they are unworkable if I'm traveling.

I've tried hooking up the drive and putting a disk in, but it doesn't offer to play it and I can't see any way to request it.

Comment: An external DVD drive (unless also externally powered) would eat the Surface's battery like MAD. :)

Comment: People say that. But when I'm tucked up in bed I can be on power. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no DVD or Blu-Ray playback codecs/capabilities included with Windows 8 RT, and (currently) no add-on ones.

You'll need to rip and convert the DVD's to a format that is playable on the Surface (RT) tablet.

Surface RT inherently supports the following video formats for playback:

- .avi
- .mp4
- .wmv
- .asf

There are *many* utilities out there to do this.

Comment: Sigh. I'll accept this even though I wish it was wrong.